# Customzed built-in element does not work in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I've been [following the guides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) to learn about custom elements. I can get the basic one to work

**JS**

```
class MyText extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log('test')
    }
}
customElements.define('my-text', MyText);
```

**HTML**

```
<my-text>Hi?</my-text>
```

**Console Output**

> test

But I cannot get the inherited format to work. It does not seem to call the constructor.

**JS**

```
class StatusText extends HTMLSpanElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {return ['status']; }

    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log("hello??");
        return this;
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log('Custom element attributes changed.');
        console.log(name, oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
customElements.define('status-text', StatusText, {extends: "span"});
```

**HTML**

```
<span is="status-text" status="ok">Hi?</span>
```

**Console Output**

(nothing)

The worst thing is, I've even tried copy-pasting this example which works on Chrome, into my own code, and somehow, it does not work for Electron..

https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/expanding-list-web-component/

What could be wrong?

**I should mention I am using electron**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it won't work until Chromium in electron is updated to 67.